# Hibernate Product is not mapped FROM Product

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

i use hibernate 5 and spring 4 mapped my class and used entity name in creating queries but i get

---

```
> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with
> path [/emusicstore] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested
> exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Product is not
> mapped [FROM Product]] with root cause
> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Product is not
> mapped
```

---

part of my codes that is necessary is included!

**my controller**

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    private ProductDaoImpl productDaoImpl;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/productList")
    public String getProduct(Model model) {
        List<Product> products = productDaoImpl.getAllProducts();
        model.addAttribute("products", products);
        return "productList";
}
```

***My Product getting Function***

```
public List<Product> getAllProducts() {
        Session session;
        try {
            session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            System.out.println("SDSDSASDASDASD");
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            System.out.println("Error in session get all");
        }
        Query query = session.createQuery("FROM Product");
        List<Product> products = query.list();

        session.flush();
        return products;
    }
```

***My applicattion Context***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl" />
        <property name="username" value="c##alireza" />
        <property name="password" value="myjava123" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.mywebsite.contorller</value>
                <value>com.mywebsite.dao.impl</value>
                <value>com.mywebsite.model</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

***tnx For ur help!***

Comment: silly question: is `Product` annotated with `@Entity`?

Answer (score 1):

In order for Hibernate to recognize your entity class, the class must be annotated with **@Entity** and located in one of the packages defined in the property **packagesToScan** of your sessionFactory.